# how to free memory allocated by a thread if the thread is killed before it frees the memory?

Tags: c, multithreading, memory, memory-management

Tried to search the answer for this question in google , but could not find it.

Consider a case where a thread is killed before it frees the memory that has been allocated at the beginning of the thread execution.

```
thread_func() {

memory is allocated in the heap using either malloc/calloc

---thread is killed while executing---

Free(memory)

}
```

How do you free the memory in such cases?

Comment: How is the thread "killed" exactly?

Comment: Depending on how your thread is killed, you could create a signal handler with the KILL SIGNAL and free the memory before the thread is finished.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is, do not terminate the thread, that is really bad design. In general, this will leave all allocated resources hanging in the free and not released until the process is closed.

Think of a way to redesign the code instead.

As an example, read the Microsoft documentation for all the risks.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686717(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: A less simple answer is that the root of the problem may not really be under the OP's control, so what can he do? I see no other solution than to "publish" allocated resources, one way or another, and free them when it is clear that the allocating thread is deceased, for example from a thread which doesn't do anything else. Oh, and I don't claim that that is perfect or fail safe or even only good -- allocating-publishing will not be atomic so that the program will still leak if the thread can die at arbitrary times; but much slower.

Comment: I think trying to clean up the killed thread's resources after the fact may make things worse, by causing crashes -- for example, imagine that the thread was killed just after it freed a particular object, but before it set a pointer to that object to NULL.  Another thread cleaning up later would likely crash when it called free() on the dangling pointer.  (You could try to avoid this sort of thing by being careful in your thread's order-of-operations, but the optimizer and out-of-order execution on modern chips will both work against you there, making that extremely difficult to do reliably)